# Automorphisms of a structure of non-zero rational numbers with multiplication

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, rational-numbers, automorphism-group

I'm given the structure $\mathcal{M} = (\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}; =; \cdot)$ and I need to prove that Aut $\mathcal{M}$ is continual. In other words, first of all, I want to find all (or at least most of) bijections $\alpha : \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ so that $\alpha(a \cdot b) = \alpha(a) \cdot \alpha(b) \;\; \forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$.

The problem is, I can't think of any automorphisms except for the identity and $\alpha(x) = \dfrac1x$, of course. I mean, let's take polynomials $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then only $\alpha(x) = x^n, n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ "saves" multiplication as mentioned above, but it's not a bijection since $\sqrt[n]{y}$ could be irrational. Same for $\alpha(x) = \dfrac1{x^n}$.

For obvious reasons, there's no way logarithms, exponential or trigonometrical functions can be used.

So I'm basically stuck in the beginning of this problem and would be glad if someone helped/gave a clue!

Comment: Given a bijective function $\alpha$ that preserves multiplication, what can you say about $\alpha(1)$? What can you say about $\alpha(1/a)$ for a given $a$ non-zero rational?

Comment: Does this recent question solve your problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3914162/7062

Comment: Does "continual" mean "of cardinality continuum ($2^{\aleph_0}$)?" (This is not standard usage in English.)

Comment: @AlexKruckman about "continual": I'm not fluent in English and just thought it's pretty ordinary to use it... anyways, thanks for the link, that answered my question!

Comment: @M.B. these are one of the first questions I answered for myself but at first I didn't give much thought to it. so having solved the problem I guess the key is to get to $\alpha(-1) = \pm 1$ and $\alpha(p/q) = \alpha(p) / \alpha(q)$, so that the only problem left is to think of bijections $\mathbb{N}_+ \to \mathbb{N}_+$. thanks for the help!